# Visible false of button in gridview while data binding? In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, I am going to disable the button while binding data, is it possible visibling false like this?

```
 <asp:Button ID ="btn" runat ="server"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id").ToString() == "1"? visble false: Visible true %>' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible='<%#getVisibility()%>' OnClick="btn_Click" />
```

Code Behind:

```
public Boolean getVisibility()
{
   Boolean b = false;
   //get the boolean value based on your field condition
   b = Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("FieldValue").ToString() != "MatchCondition" ? "true" :     "false");
   return b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it in the DataGrid RowDataBound event

Answer (score 2):

Either do that in the data bound event or do it like this...

```
<asp:Button ID ="btn" runat ="server" Visible='<%# Eval("id").ToString() == "1"? "false" : "true" %>' />
```